# Nvidia card going bad(?) I would like to use the system with reduced video

Tags: nvidia, graphics, configuration

I have an old computer (HP Pavilliion dv9700) that still has utility.  The display is whacko: triangles, oversized dialog boxes, windows overlapping.  Everything is fine until the GUI starts, even the Ubuntu logo.  If I can get the video to run in the same configuration as it is during boot, I'll have a workable system.

But how do I do that?
Ubuntu 20.04 (and 22.04 and to a lessor extent 18.04) with kernel *5.15.0-41-generic* and *NVIDIA Corporation C67 [GeForce 715M / nForce 630M (rev a2)*

Here's what I've done:
I've tried changing the resolution and refresh but to no avail.
Loaded **Windows 10 and looks fine** "1024x768 8-bit RGB Standard Dynamic Range (SDR)"

I think I need an old Nvidia driver. [see](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/71379/en-us/):
Programs needed to compile driver:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev net-tools cifs-utils openssh-server gcc make flex -y
```

But I get this error message:

```
ERROR: If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
       you either have configured kernel sources matching your
       kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
       on your system.

       If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
       you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
       installed on your system. If you specified a separate
       output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
       the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
       directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

       Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
       kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
       their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.
```

Am I on the right track that I need the Nvidia driver?  If so, "How do I resolve this error?"  If not, is there a generic video driver that works on just about every video card?

Hope to hear from you.

Old Surfer Dude

Comment: You've not provided any product or release details..   On some older hardware, I find using the older kernel stack can help; but the options available to you vary on what product/release you're using & you gave no details, thus we cannot know if any GA/HWE/OEM kernel stack choices exist for you.  Also FYI:  In recent ~week the *focal* systems (using HWE) switched from 5.13 to 5.15 kernel & this maybe what led to your issue, but you didn't provide release details so we can only speculated as to cause/fixes.. If that's you; switching to the GA kernel stack could possibly be an easy fix.

Comment: @guiverc  I am not as skilled as you.  Can you please provide me on how to gather the information one would need to be able to get help, like "product/release"?  What is "GA/HWE/OEM kernel stack"  and "focal systems"?  I don't have a clue what "GA kernel stack" is?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, ie. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release of Ubuntu (*2000 is dded to year; Ubuntu didn't exist before 2004*). You didn't provide your release details (the most important detail we need to know)). Some *specialist* releases also use the *year* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 22 being the 2022 release of that product, but they are server only products, all desktop releases are *year.month* in format.  If you provided details of what you installed I'd have all details (eg. if you installed Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I'd know it was GA kernel stack of 20.04)

Comment: If however you installed Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I'd know you're using 20.04 with a HWE kernel stack as that's used for installs with .2 media or later. Regardless the command `uname -r` will give you details of your running kernel, eg. my own answer is 5.15.0-35.  Only the first two numbers here matter; 5.15 is my kernel & 0-35 show upgrades applied. The release is most important, the kernel stack detail can be provided via kernel being used (5.15 here; though note: you have no idea what release I'm using from 5.15 as that kernel is a GA stack for one release; HWE for another, both are needed)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for example could be used with the older GA kernel stack (ie. 5.4), or with an updated HWE stack (which changed to 5.8 from Ubuntu 20.10, 5.11 from Ubuntu 21.04, 5.13 from Ubuntu 21.10 before finally reaching 5.15 from 22.04 only very recently)...  If you're using Ubuntu 22.04 now, you'll be on 5.15 kernel (*unless you're using an OEM kernel which is machine specific*), ie. I'd expect 5.15 from a `uname -r` command like I used in example.  There are no HWE stack option yet for 22.04; they won't start until after 22.10 is released in October 2022..

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418466/edit) your question and add your release details there.. When comments no longer apply they'll get deleted/removed. Comments are intended for us to speak to you, you edit the question with the details requested etc (*then comments get removed*).  A cleaner question (*no comments*) can attract more readers/replies.

Comment: If you want to test out another kernel stack, you don't need to install anything, but download a Ubuntu ISO using that stack, write it to thumb-drive & test using *live* media; ie. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install applies to all Ubuntu and *flavors* or Ubuntu. If the issue occurred very recently (days-week or two ago), it's likely related to the 5.15 kernel that recently rolled out to 20.04 users; switching to the GA kernel stack was the fix for 20.04, but by moving to 22.04 both GA & HWE currently use the 5.15 kernel that is the *new* HWE option for Ubuntu 20.04